# Permission denied. Could not perform this operation when using react-firebase-file-uploader

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I was trying to upload CSV file to `firebase` using `react-firebase-file-uploader` package.

I have set the firebase configuration but when i upload a csv file, I got this `403` error:

```
error: {
  code: 403
  message: "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"
}
```

I have changed the rules in `firebase store` like this and it worked.

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow write: if true;
      allow read: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

but when I change it to this it sends me error again:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow write: if request.auth != null;
      allow read: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

firebase/index.js file

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "XXXXXX",
  authDomain: "xxx.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://xxx.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "xxx",
  storageBucket: "xxx.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXX",
  appId: "1:XXX:web:XXX"
};

export default firebaseConfig;
```

I have set configuration in index.js (root component)file in `src` folder.

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import firebaseConfig from './firebase';


firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
...
```

It should work when i change the rule to enable only when there's auth data in request in `firebase configuration`.

Comment: Are you using Firebase Authentication? Is there a user signed in at the time of the upload?

Comment: no, I am using my own authentication logic.
there is a user signed in at the time of the upload

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line in your rules:

```
  allow write: if request.auth != null;
```

requires that a user be signed in with Firebase Authentication.  Other forms of authentication will not work - it has to be through one of the providers (or custom auth) supported by Firebase Authentication.

Firebase security rules don't support any other type of authentication.

Comment: Is possible to add rules to specify document (or field from document)?